# D3 Only Loading One Cell of Data

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

I have a http.server running on my 8888 port using python.

I am attempting to a load tsv file into the Day/Hour Heatmap: 
[a link]http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084#data.tsv

Note that both the data.tsv file and the code

The output below is what I'm seeing in my Chrome browser when navigating to the appropriate file. It is not loading the full amount of data.

[image]

(this is admittedly my first pass using D3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      rect.bordered {
        stroke: #E6E6E6;
        stroke-width:2px;   
      }

      text.mono {
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Consolas, courier;
        fill: #aaa;
      }

      text.axis-workweek {
        fill: #000;
      }

      text.axis-worktime {
        fill: #000;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
          legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
          buckets = 9,
          colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
          days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
          times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];


      d3.tsv("data.csv",
        function(d) {
          return {
            day: +d.day,
            hour: +d.hour,
            value: +d.value
          };
        },
        function(error, data) {
          var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
              .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
              .range(colors);

          var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
              .data(days)
              .enter().append("text")
                .text(function (d) { return d; })
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
                .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

          var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
              .data(times)
              .enter().append("text")
                .text(function(d) { return d; })
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
                .attr("y", 0)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
                .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

          var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)
              .attr("class", "hour bordered")
              .attr("width", gridSize)
              .attr("height", gridSize)
              .style("fill", colors[0]);

          heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

          heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });

          var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; })
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend");

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
            .attr("y", height)
            .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
            .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("class", "mono")
            .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
            .attr("y", height + gridSize);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some of your code.

Comment: Two possible problems I can see: (1) You're never checking your `error` value.  If you're getting a file-reading error, then `data` will be a single undefined element (though you shouldn't get *any* squares then). (2)Your file name is ".csv" but you're using `tsv` methods.  If your data is comma-separated, then all the properties of the data will be concatenated together ( `d["day,hour,value"]="1,10,14"`).  Can you try it again, first:check that `error` is undefined and you're not getting any errors on the console; second: print out the value of `data` so you know what it *is* reading in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks right and since its exactly the way it is shown in the example, the problem might be with your data file.
Getting data only in the first grid means your x and y values are not getting properly rendered.
.attr("**x**", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
.attr("**y**", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })

Are the names day and hour correctly written? (even caps creates problem - something like Day and Hour instead of day and hour)

Hope this helps.